# PMOS unexpectedly passing current with capacitor on drain

Tags: capacitor, mosfet, circuit-analysis, high-pass-filter

I am designing a circuit to get a pulse when a switch opens. When the voltage source V1 is connected, the switch SW1 starts closed. I want Vout to briefly go high when SW1 opens. The circuit I designed looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXlaZ9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, I get the opposite behaviour to what I expected when the circuit is turned on. When SW1 is closed, I would expect the drain of the MOSFET to be at 0V and pass no current. Instead, it charges the capacitor up to 2V. Then when the switch opens, the capacitor is already charged, and I don't get a pulse. According to the theory I read, when the MOSFET vSG = 0V then iD = 0A. Why is current flowing; do I need a more sophisticated model?

Comment: You need to add a pull-down resistor from the MOSFET drain to Ground.

Comment: 1. How is the capacitor ever supposed to discharge? 2. While SW1 is open, the capacitor charges up to 2V. Then when you close the switch the current indeed does go to 0A, but the capacitor is already charged, and without any way to discharge it it stays charged.

Comment: @DKNguyen after the capacitor delivers the pulse, the device is shut down so V1 is disconnected. After it is shut down it has at least 12 hours to self-discharge.

Comment: @bobbob Oh, this is only meant to run "once"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a simulation?

The leakage current from the MOSFET will charge the capacitor - it is probable that the simulator waits for conditions to stabilize before you get to time zero.

I suggest putting a resistor from the drain to ground. It can be fairly high, eg 1 megohm, to bypass the leakage current. You will also need the resistor to discharge the capacitor and allow the circuit to produce a pulse the second time the switch opens.

Also, many simulators will not function correctly if any nodes do not have a DC path to ground.

Comment: The capacitor charges anyways when the switch is open.

Comment: @DKNguyen - the simulation starts with the switch closed.

Comment: @KevinWhite unfortunately it's not a simulation, it is happening on a physical PCB. I didn't catch this while simulating. I'll try a 10M pulldown (every uA is important) to see if it's strong enough.

Comment: Remember that the larger that pulldown is, the longer it will be until you can get another pulse, since the capacitor has to discharge through the pulldown.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis That is not critical since the time between pulses should exceed the capacitor's self-discharge rate.

Comment: @bobbob - what voltage do you measure at the capacitor? I wouldn't have expected the capacitor to show any voltage in the real world as normal DVMs have 10Megohm input resistance that would discharge the cap anyway.

Comment: @bobbob - what circuit does this feed a pulse to? I can think of many better ways to create a pulse, it may be possible to integrate the pulse creation into the following circuit.

Comment: In the end I couldn't use a resistor because low enough resistance to prevent the capacitor getting charged would pass too much current when the FET was on. I ended up completely redesigning this section, making a software rather than hardware implementation.

Comment: @KevinWhite I was measuring the high pass signal at vout with an 1GHz, 1Mohm oscilloscope. When the switch closed (and the capacitor wasn't already charged by leakage) I saw the exponential signal decreasing from 2-0V. As you said, measuring across the capacitors with the scope quickly discharged them with tau=1ms, you could see the waveform on the oscilloscope screen.

Comment: @KevinWhite Yes, this was not the best implementation for what I was trying to get out of the design. I abandoned this approach for a more flexible software solution.